# iOS in app purchase questions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

Okay I am working on Auto renewable iOS in app purchase and after a lot of time i havn't found a single blog or a proper documentation of the feature.

Q1. When does the amount actually get deducted from users, if there is a trial period of say 7 days in a monthly subscription?

Q2. What if users want to upgrade the subscription during an already subscription time? Does the time for previous subscription and the new one gets appended?
Suppose there is a monthly and yearly subscription. In the 10th day of subscribing to the monthly one a users decides to upgrade the subscription to a yearly one. How will be my application know when the upgrade began? and will the user then avail for 1 year and 20 days (coz 20 days were still left) of subscription?

Q3. What if the User cancels the subscription in between the subscription? How will my application know that? What if the user cancels the subscription in the trial period?

These questions are haunting me and i haven't found a single article or documentation that answers these. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after tons and tons of rnd on this i finally wrote my own class and as far for the answers

1. Yes only after trail period is **over**, user is charged.
2. Doesn't matter as its about subscription. The only detail matters is is the subscription still on or not, So after 15 days if user wants to subscribe **then the user will have the new upgraded subscription after the end of the CURRENT subscription**.

   Meaning if user is using a 1 month subscription, and user started the subscription on say 1st of the month, and upgrades to 60 day subscription on the 17th day. Then the new 60-day subscription will start on the 2nd of the next month i,e when the current subscription will end.
3. If user cancels the subscription, it can be known after we get the response from apple, after hitting apple server with the current receipt.

   I wrote a class which takes the users receipt and calls Apple and checks for any subscription, and lets user knows the current subscription details and also the previous subscription ones. User can also use the class for buying a new subscription.
   Here is the link for the Model. [SRSubscriptionModel](https://github.com/SahebRoy92/SRSubscriptionModel)

I totally forgot about this answer and thanks for the comments above.I want people not to go through the hassle I went through as there is no such good libraries NOR a proper documentation provided from Apple.

P.S - The library i wrote is working as expected. Currently I have a live application in AppStore that uses this library.